# How to find out qrcode orientation using ZXing?

Tags: delphi, zxing, vcl

I am using the ZXing porting for Delphi from [Spelt/ZXing.Delphi](https://github.com/Spelt/ZXing.Delphi) using VCL and Delphi Rio

I am scanning documentos, actually receipts using a fast fujitsu scanner. It is a huge quantity.

The problem is that besides the orientation of the paper ZXing always read the qrcode on it (that is perfectly fine).

However for archival purposes should be nice to save the document in the proper horizontal position.

This is the code I am using to get the qrcode value:

```
function TFormMain.DecodificaQRCodeImagemScanneada(ImagemScanneada: TBitmap): String;
var
  scanBitmap: TBitmap;
  ResultadoLeitura: TReadResult;
  ScanManager: TScanManager;
begin
  result := '';
  try
      ScanManager := TScanManager.Create(TBarcodeFormat.Auto, nil);
      scanBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
      scanBitmap.Assign(ImagemScanneada);
      ResultadoLeitura := nil;
      ResultadoLeitura := ScanManager.Scan(scanBitmap);
      if (ResultadoLeitura <> nil) then
      begin
        result :=  ResultadoLeitura.Text;
      end;
  finally
    ResultadoLeitura.Free;
    scanBitmap.Free;
    ScanManager.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I would like to know if there is a way to get the orientation of the qrcode, using it as an indicator of the position of the receipt scanned. So I can rotate the bitmap and have all the receipts oriented the same way.